# TypeError: client.execute is not a function

Tags: discord.js

most if not all commands start to not work.

not sure what type of code i should have put it in so i put it in css

[What comes out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTxNg.png)

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2TIV.png)

```css
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;

    const prefixRegex = new RegExp(`^(<@!?${client.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(config.prefix)})\\s*`);
  if (!prefixRegex.test(message.content)) return;

  const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex);

  const args = message.content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command =
    client.commands.get(commandName) ||
    client.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

  if (!command) return;

  if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
  }

  const now = Date.now();
  const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
  const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 1) * 1000;

  if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

    if (now < expirationTime) {
      const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
      return message.reply(
        `please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`
      );
    }
  }

  timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
  setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

  try {
    command.execute(message, args);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply("There was an error executing that command.").catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

Just having problems with finding a better function for replacement of command.execute
please and thank you it would be the world for me.

Comment: How do your command files look like?

Comment: What is `console.error(error);` return to you `TypeError: client.execute is not a function` if this is errors log please make sure `command` is valid and it have `execute()` function

Answer (score -1):

```
client.commands.get(commandName).execute(message, args);
```

replace `command.execute(message, args);` with this^ and it should work.

If that doesnt work i suggest you put

```
if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        }
    
        return message.channel.send(reply);
        }
```

right before the `if (!command) return`

Hope this helps and please correct me if said anything wrong

Comment: How is the first part better if `const command = client.commands.get(commandName)`? And what does the second part of your answer have to do with OP's question?